# I am sending raw JSON data through postman to a PHP function (PUT method). file_get_contents('php://input') gives null

Tags: php, api, postman, file-get-contents, put

I am trying to get the raw data passed through `$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));` but `file_get_contents('php://input')` gives an empty string (instead of the raw data that I passed)

Some more information if it helps:

- allow_url_fopen is on in php.ini
- I am using PUT method to send data
- Content-Type is `application/json`

[Postman 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0U2Tt.png)
[Postman 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfHBA.png)

Comment: And exactly how you'r sending this `json` data to php script/function through postman?

Comment: I am sorry but I am unable to understand what you mean. If this helps, the data is {"name":"some name", "email":"some email"}

Comment: I mean, are you calling any api? and can you share the screenshot of postman with headers and is this the code from that api to which you are submitting the `PUT` request?

Comment: Yes, its the code that my is accessed when I call the API, I will attach the screenshot to the question

Comment: Are you using any php framework in the backend? Also, can you share `.htaccess` (_if being used_) and apache configuration file of production

Answer (score 0):

I try to reproduce your problem but it's working fine for me.

1/ my php file : `<?php  $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); print_r($_POST); ?>`

2/  The postman request and response (PUT Method)
[Postman request and response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nurd6.png)

Try to use postman for testing and if it's working, check the way you send data to your script.

Comment: Update: It works in dev and not in prod. Everything is same, I am tired. Also, I tried changing the method to POST and it works for prod as well. It just does not work for PUT in prod.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't override the `$_POST` variable, that's a bad practice.
2. Setting a content-type header isn't enough. You have to encode and send the data correctly. In postman you should send it like so:

[image]

Make sure you set body type to *raw*, and sending a valid JSON.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly how I am doing it. Also, I just came to know it works well in dev and not in prod, all the code is same! Also, in prod, it works fine for POST method though

Comment: @HetalMangukia Then you should look at your server configuration (Nginx / Apache) and make sure PUT method is enabled.

Comment: That sounds like a problem. Unfortunately, I do not know how to see if the PUT method is enabled or not, and if disabled, how to enable it. Can you help me through that?

Comment: Just checked it and PUT method is enabled!